# get ItemTapped Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin and I am trying to get an item key and value when you select it on a dictionary listview .

here is my function:

```
public async void OnSelectedLanguages(object obj, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
        {

            var language = args.Item as Dictionary<string, string>;

            Console.WriteLine("lang " + args.Item);


        }
```

when I print "args.Item", I have this on output: "lang  [japan, ja]"

I cannot see how I can get  "japan" and "ja" in order to put it in variables.

I have tried this : var language = args.Item as Dictionary;

but "language" seems to be empty

and I have this when I print "args.Item.GetType":

```
"System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]"
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description tells you exactly what to do - you should cast `args.Item` to `KeyValuePair`.